# How to create a template by html and css in vbulletin 4.2.1

Tags: html, css, templates, vbulletin

I would like to create a html/css template about rating thread for my forum.

I researched on internet and I found many information about this but just a very simple example, I can't understand the step to create that I want. I use flow above and it work, but I need detail example to make it for me!

Add a Plugin to your Product

Goto Plugins & Products -> Add New Plugin
Select your Product
To add something to the header on every page select the global_bootstrap_init_complete hook location
In PHP code enter the following:

```
$template_hook['mycustommesage'] = 'hello world';
```

Update your header template to include the plugin output

In ACP goto Styles & Templates -> Style Manager
Select the style you want to edit and select edit templates
Open the header template
Whereever you want you plugin output to appear add:

```
{vb:raw template_hook.mycustommesage}
```

Anyone lead me step by step about this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this first you should create a default template from:

ACP > Styles & Templates > Style Generator

** set Parent Style on vbulletin default style **

after that you can edit vbulletin code from:

ACP > Styles & Templates > Search in Templates

for example you want to add a dive in header, you should search header and edit header section

for adding css codes you should search and edit additional.css

and for adding tag to  , like adding js or any css file , search headinclude or headinclude_bottom

I hope that is useful